# Why is my Excel document printing on legal paper, but with letter margins?

Tags: macos, printing, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2008, microsoft-excel-2008

I am trying to print an Excel spreadsheet, which is rather large.  I want it to be only one page wide, and as many pages tall as is necessary.  I want the font to be as large as possible, as long as it is only one page wide.

So, in the print dialog, I told it to fit to 1 page wide, by [blank] pages tall.  I selected US Legal for the Destination Paper size and checked Scale to fit paper size (unchecking Scale down only) on the Paper Handling screen.  In Page Setup, I chose landscape.

I also tried specifying how many pages tall I wanted the document, but it had no affect.  So, if when that field was blank, the document was 5 pages tall, I tried putting in 6, or 7.  The document stayed at 5 pages tall, and didn't use any additional width.

In print preview, I am seeing that it is planning to use Legal paper, but it is not using the full width.  It seems to have the same border it would use for letter paper.

I am running MS Office 2008 on Mac OS 10.5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set the paper size in **Page Setup >> Options** rather than in the Paper Handling section of the Print menu. I can't quite figure out what the size option in Paper Handling does, but the paper size from Page Options seems to trump it.

Answer (score 1):

I would populate the second field with the number of pages manually until the preview looks passable. Keep changing it until you find one that works for you.

Comment: I actually did try that, and it just doesn't use those extra pages.  I will update the question to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that when you are printing select the properties and then paper in that page select the correct page size and click ok. Now print the document.